# What does the discovery of pressure of black holes imply for spacetime thermodynamics?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, pressure, ads-cft, holographic-principle

As far as I know AdS/CFT and spacetime thermodynamics was motivated by the Bekenstein-Hawking Entropy formula of black holes.
[Recently](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.066012) however it was discovered that black holes have a pressure as well.
Does this have any implications for spacetime thermodynamics?

Comment: Could you provide a reference on what you mean by "black holes have a pressure as well"? In the 80s, BH Thermodynamics already used a notion of pressure to understand how the Generalized Second Law can keep consistency and to learn how to mine energies from black holes (DOI: [10.1103/PhysRevD.25.942](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.25.942), DOI: [10.1007/BF00759206](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00759206)). Is this what you mean or something else?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves I suspect it's about this: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.066012 "Quantum gravitational corrections to the entropy of a Schwarzschild black hole" by 
Xavier Calmet and Folkert Kuipers (Published 9 September 2021). Pressure pops out in the related release for the public: https://phys.org/news/2021-09-black-holes-exert-pressure-environment.html#:~:text=Physicists%20at%20the%20University%20of,black%20holes%20emit%20thermal%20radiation.

Comment: @Quillo Yes that's the one. I added it in the question.

Comment: Related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/341236/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695574/226902

Comment: The link in the second question you provided was useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The pressure of Schwarzschild black holes arises as a consequence of the quantum corrections due to local and non-local terms in the effective quantum gravity action.

For a Schwarzschild black hole it was found in [$[1]$](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.066012) that

$$P_{q,S} = − \gamma \frac{1}{2 G^4_N M^4}$$

where $\gamma$ is a constant appearing in the non-local part of the action.

However, charged (Reissner-Nordström) black holes do possess a classical pressure [$[2]$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269309000537), which is proportional to the charge, and hence is zero for Schwarzschild:

$$ P_{cl,RN}=-\frac{Q^2}{64\pi G^4_NM^4} $$

Quantum gravity effects modify this classical expression too. The full expression for the pressure was found in [$[3]$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-022-10232-0) (with some approximations) and is

$$ P_{RN}=P_{cl,RN}+P_{q,S}+P_{q,RN}Q^2$$

where $P_{q,RN}$ is the a slightly more complicated generalisation of $P_{q,S}$:

\begin{multline}
    P_{q,RN}=\frac{1}{32G^5_NM^6}\Big[c_2+4c_3+2\beta(\gamma_E-4)+8\gamma(\gamma_E-5)+2(\beta+4\gamma)\ln(2G_NM\mu)\Big]
    \\+\frac{\pi}{9G^6_NM^8}\bigg\{54(\beta+4\gamma)\Big[c_1+2\alpha\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\Big]
    +72(3\gamma_E-7)\beta\Big[c_2+2\beta\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\Big]\\
    +768(3\gamma_E-7)\gamma\Big[c_3+2\gamma\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\Big]
    +6\Big[c_2\gamma(120\gamma_E-287)+3c_3\beta(40\gamma_E-91)\\
    +160\beta\gamma(3\gamma_E-7)\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\Big]
     +54\Big[c^2_2+4c_2\beta\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)+4\beta^2\ln^2\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\Big]\\
   +576\Big[c^2_3+4c_3\gamma\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)+4\gamma^2\ln^2\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\Big]
   +360\Big[c_2c_3+2c_2\gamma\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\\+2c_3\beta\ln\left(2G_NM\mu\right)
    +4\beta\gamma\ln^2\left(2G_NM\mu\right)\Big]+(\beta+4\gamma)\Big[36\alpha(3\gamma_E-7) \\+9\beta\big(8\gamma_E(3\gamma_E-14)+95+4\pi^2\big)
    +\gamma\big(192\gamma_E(3\gamma_E-14)+2095+120\pi^2\big)\Big]  
    \bigg\}.
    \end{multline}

Here, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ belong to the non-local part of the action, $c_1,c_2,c_3$ belong to the local part.

The quantum corrections do not only modify the pressure, but also the entropy, the temperature etc. The effective field theory method for quantum gravity is useful because you can keep track of the quantum effects easily.

**References**

[$[1]$](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.104.066012) X. Calmet and F. Kuipers. Quantum gravitational corrections to the entropy of a Schwarzschild black hole. Phys. Rev. D **104** , 066012 (2021).

[$[2]$](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269309000537)Y.-H. Wei. Understanding first law of thermodynamics of black holes. Phys. Lett. B **672** 98–100 (2009).

[$[3]$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-022-10232-0) Campos Delgado, R. Quantum gravitational corrections to the entropy of a Reissner–Nordström black hole. Eur. Phys. J. C **82**, 272 (2022).